# How to initialise RgbColor from ability_main.xml?

Tags: java, android, huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers, harmonyos

I have a custom attribute of type RgbColor in my library, I wanted to know how can I initialise it to a specific color of my choice using ability_main.xml?

Comment: hi@Shrey Shrivastava, Could you pls post some code of your library for us to locate your issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can check the below example code:
If this is the xml code with custom attribute (backgroundColor)

```
 <com.example.application.CustomView
        ohos:width="300vp"
        ohos:height="100vp"
        app:backgroundColor="#FF000000">
```

In CustomView.java, if backgroundColor value is being assigned to a RgbColor object, then you cantry this below code

```
if (attrs.getAttr(BACKGROUND_COLOR).isPresent() && attrs.getAttr(BACKGROUND_COLOR).get() != null) {
            mBackgroundColor = new RgbColor(attrs.getAttr(BACKGROUND_COLOR).get().getIntegerValue());
}
```